# How do I turn autosave on?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I keep saving my game manually with the phone but it's a bit of a hassle. I've been told this game has an autosave that saves after every mission but this doesn't seem to be the case.

How do I turn the autosave on?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: I think he's trying to say he turned the autosave off.

Comment: OP, open the pause menu and go to the game tab. There should be an option there to turn the autosave on and off. Turn it on.

Answer (score 3):

Open the pause menu and go to the game tab. There should be an option there to turn the autosave on and off. Turn it on and you will save automatically after every mission.

Answer (score 1):

Its on the Settings tab, actually. (for me at least)
Pause>Settings>Saving>Autosave

In PC:
Pause>Settings>Saving And Startup>Autosave

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Settings/Saving/Autosave* in the pause menu.

Make sure autosave is on like in this screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Press go to the pause menu.
go to settings.
go to Saving and startup
then go to autosave and go from off to on.

Answer (score -1):

Pause -> Settings -> Saving -> Autosave On/Off

Comment: Please, avoid writing everything with caps lock.