# How can I save my progress on GTA 5 in the middle of a mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Sometimes I need to get off of the game while I’m in the middle of a mission but I can’t find a way to save besides ending the mission.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131571/how-can-i-save-my-progress)

Comment: Voting to leave open. This is answered (barely) by a comment on another answer there.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't. You have two options:

You can quit the game and rely on your autosave. See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156929/how-do-i-turn-autosave-on) for how to turn it on and when it saves. There's no way not to lose your progress in the current mission though.

Alternatively, you could leave the game paused, assuming that's practical.